# Refer to another worksheet that has increment in cell number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet (let me call it WorksheetA) that each row has a different information. Then, I want to refer this information per row on my other worksheet (WorksheetB).

To explain further, WorksheetA has 2 columns that should be copied to WorksheetB. These are Name and School Last Attended. I want to know how can WorksheetB be updated every time a new row in WorksheetA is filled.

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: There are three ways to do this.  One is to pre-populate WorksheetB with formulas that stay hidden until a value is entered in WorkshhetA.  Another is to use VBA to place the value in WorksheetB when triggered by an entry in WorksheetA.  The third is to use an approach like what is described in Rust's answer to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/822617/excel-x-y-scatter-chart-more-than-one-value-per-cell/822620#822620.

Answer (score 0):

Say we are using *Sheet1* and *Sheet2.*  In *Sheet2* cell **A1** enter:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1="","",Sheet1!A1)
```

Then copy **A1** to **B1**

Then copy both **A1** and **B1** downwards.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that there is only one cell in WorksheetB for the Name value. And also, only one cell for Last School Attended. It would be really helpful if the answer for my question is within the environment of Excel, that I won't require to use any other software/program. Thanks!!